# additional "/" (slash) from response assertion is showing in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, assertion

I want to use response assertion to match the response from server, here when I am getting responses it shows like {
"per_page": 6,
"total": 12,
"data": [
{
"last_name": "Lawson",
"id": 7,
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg",
"first_name": "Michael",
"email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in"
},

But in response assertion it showing like
Assertion failure message:Test failed: text expected to contain /{
"per_page": 6,
"total": 12,
"data": [
{
"last_name": "Lawson",
"id": 7,
"avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg",
"first_name": "Michael",
"email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in"
},
{
and therefor it gets failing even though its matching but due to addition / (slash), its getting failed.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

JMeter doesn't "add" slashes anywhere, it's just a matter of visualization, you're getting your pattern surrounded with slashes as there is a mismatch, basically JMeter fails to find what you put in the "Patterns to test" in the application response

Demo:

[image]

See lines 472 and 480 in the [ResponseAssertion source](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/components/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/assertions/ResponseAssertion.java#L472)

So make sure that your response contains the pattern and be aware that every line brake or empty space matters so if your server returns non-formatted string and you're expecting a "pretty" one - the assertion will fail.

We cannot suggest the best option without seeing you actual response, however full-text comparing 2 JSON entities doesn't seem a good approach to me in terms of robustness and reliability, you might want to consider [JSON Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Assertion) or [JSON JMESPath Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide) instead

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your response, what could be the best way to compare the entire response from server to actual response, as of now I am using Response Assertion in which expected response is putting in Pattern to test

Comment: The "best" way is to [limit usage of assertions to the necessary minimum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean)  because they have their cost, consume resources, impact throughput, etc. so I would check the number of items (i.e. 12) or just that you're getting a JSON-line structure. However if you're [using JMeter for functional testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-backend-based-functional-testing) and don't care about resources switch pattern matching rule to `Equals`, copy server response and paste it to "Patterns to test"

Comment: Yes Dmitri, I am doing API automation testing in Jmeter, so not worrying about resources,  I just want to check server response to expected response, hence I was trying with response assertion but getting additional / (slash) and assertion is getting failed

Comment: Man, your assertion is not failing due to slash, you're seeing slash because your assertion fails, just cross check the pattern with the response and you will see why

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same problem. But this assertion not trimming your response. So check you have additional space or line at the end of actual response end. If you give the addition space or line it will pass.